# Does the following code disable ASLR?

Tags: c, aslr

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  personality(ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE);

  if (fork())
  {
    return 0;
  }

  printf("Hook me")
```

I encountered this code in an exercise. Based on my reckoning, this should disable ASLR on the child process. However, I used LD_PRELOAD to sleep the binary on printf and attach with gdb at that point. I at this point I noticed that ASLR appears to be enabled, based on stack addresses varying. Aslr is definitely enabled in the parent process.

Should ASLR be disabled on the child process?  What's wrong with the code preventing ASLR from being disabled in the forked child?

Answer (score 1):

That will not work with `fork` as `fork` makes an exact copy of the parent's (ASLR enabled) address space. Try with `exec` instead and it should work.